# Computing hash for custom AST struct

Tags: c++, hash, hashmap, compiler-construction, hashcode

I was implementing a compiler and in the Dragon Book, they talk about using DAGs to represent expressions rather than a plan Abstract Syntax Tree. To compute a Hash for a struct, I came up with a more or less "random" approach.

```
struct FloatNode : public ASTNode {
        float val;

        explicit FloatNode(float val) : val(val) {}

        size_t computeHash() override {
            return (*reinterpret_cast<int *>(&val)) << 16;
        }
    };
```

Is this an efficient method to accomplish this task? Also, are there more suitable algorithms to do this?

Comment: What's the logic in removing the high-order 16 bits? Were you perhaps thinking about right-shifting? Either way, it's not portable for many reasons, and it really doesn't strike me as a good idea. But it's your call.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on a decent implementation?

Comment: Looks okay, but I'd recommend using something like [std::unordered_map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map), which [uses a hash](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash) of [size_t](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t). It'll guide you on what else you need to define, like equality.

Comment: @ishaangupte: the portable solution to get the bits out ofa float/double is to memcpy into an unsigned integer of the correct size (selecting the integer type useasier in C++ than in C). But you also need to watch out for NaNs and negative zeros because of the weirdness of floating point equality.

Comment: Also, dropping the low-order bits (if that's what you were trying to do) is probably not a good idea. It's true that there are common classes of floats whise low-order bits are all zero (notably, small integers), but there probably aren't a lot of different small integer floating point literals in a typical program. On the other hand, only hashing the equivalent of  two high order decimal digits could well create lots of false collisions. The underlying problem is converting the hash to an index by bitmasking. That's suboptimal; use a rotate+xor or multiply+add to mix the bits.